# @Unowned orm annotation in datanucleus-appengine 2.0

Tags: google-app-engine, orm, jdo, datanucleus

What is the .jdo xml equivalent of @Unowned annotation? If I leave an @Unowned annotation inside my domain class, will mysql orm of that class be affected in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in package-gae.orm, and have a separate package-mysql.orm for MySQL usage

```
<extension vendor-name="datanucleus" key="gae.unowned" value="true"/>
```

Comment: can I use model-gae.jdo or package-gae.jdo?